# python multiprocessing manager connect creates another object

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I would like to create shared object among processes. First I created server process which spawned process for class `ProcessClass`. Then I created another process where I want to connect to shared object.

But connection from another process created its own instance of `ProcessClass`.
So what I need to do to access this remote shared object.
Here is my test code.

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from multiprocessing import Process


class ProcessClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._state = False

    def set(self):
        self._state = True

    def get(self):
        return self._state


class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass


def another_process():
    MyManager.register('my_object')
    m = MyManager(address=('', 50000))
    m.connect()
    proxy = m.my_object()

    print(f'state from another process: {proxy.get()}')


def test_spawn_and_terminate_process():
    MyManager.register('my_object', ProcessClass)

    m = MyManager(address=('', 50000))
    m.start()

    proxy = m.my_object()
    proxy.set()
    print(f'state from main process: {proxy.get()}')

    p = Process(target=another_process)
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(f'state from main process: {proxy.get()}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_spawn_and_terminate_process()
```

Output is

```
python test_communication.py
state from main process: True
state from another process: False
state from main process: True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working as it is supposed to. If you look at the documentation for `multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager` you will see that there is, for example, a method `dict()` to create a shareable dictionary. Would you expect that calling this method multiple times would return the same dictionary over and over again or new instances of sharable dictionaries?

What you need to do is enforce a singleton instance to be used repeatedly for successive invocations of `proxy = m.my_object()` and the way to do that is to first define the following function:

```py
singleton = None

def get_singleton_process_instance():
    global singleton
    if singleton is None:
        singleton = ProcessClass()
    return singleton
```

Then you need to make a one line change in funtion `test_spawn_and_terminate_process`:

```
def test_spawn_and_terminate_process():
    #MyManager.register('my_object', ProcessClass)
    MyManager.register('my_object', get_singleton_process_instance)
```

This ensures that to satisfy requests for 'my_object', it always invokes `get_singleton_process_instance()` (returning the singleton) instead of `ProcessClass()`, which would return a new instance.